# PostgreSQL: Insert into JSONB key failing with syntax error at or near "->>"

Tags: postgresql

Running the following query auto-generated by Eloquent's upsert function is throwing a syntax error and I'm not sure why? I couldn't find a supporting statement that says PostgreSQL supports the following syntax, looking for some expert advice on whether this would work.

```
insert into "plugin_positions" 
("created_at", "positions"->>"test", "slug", "tag", "updated_at") 
values 
('2021-04-10 17:30:40', 0, 'contact-for-telegram', 'rrss', '2021-04-10 17:30:40');
```

Here's the query that works *(which uses the simple column name, and a valid json value)*:

```
insert into "plugin_positions" 
("created_at", "positions", "slug", "tag", "updated_at") 
values 
('2021-04-10 17:30:40', '{"test":0}', 'contact-for-telegram', 'rrss', '2021-04-10 17:30:40');
```

Does postgresql allow inserting into a table if we specify the column as `"positions"->>"test"`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Please **always** include your PostgreSQL version in any questions... Can you run similar queries just using the **psql** client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the attributes of a JSON column are not database columns, so you cannot use them in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` statement.

You can only replace the complete JSON with an `UPDATE` statement.

It might be a good idea to use regular "scalar" database columns instead of lumping several attributes together into a JSON if you want to modify them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [JSON FUNCTIONS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) for purpose on that positioin.

At your position `("created_at", "positions"->>"test"` it expects a column name.

You may have a problem with eloquent, so you should ask at SO

What you can do, after some thinking is something like

```
DO $$
BEGIN

EXECUTE CONCAT('insert into "plugin_positions" ("created_at",', "positions"->>"test" , E', "slug", "tag", "updated_at") VALUES  (''2021-04-10 17:30:40'', 0, ''contact-for-telegram'', ''rrss'', ''2021-04-10 17:30:40'');');
END $$;
   ;
```

This dynamic sql would make your insert, with the json "positions"